# Get a list of friends with installed app from game's server (Vkontakte API)

Tags: api, integration, vk

I need to get a list of friends with installed app from game's server by VK API.

Send this data from client is not security, 'cause server can not be sure, that data is valid. Method friend.getAppUsers is not avaliable from server. There is one more variant: to get a list of friends and check each by isAppUser. But this procedure can process over, than 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any news ? smart solutions ? some thing? any thing ?

---

**idea 0**

- get all friends with friends.get
- select user from your_local_database where uid = vkontakte_uid
- be happy :p

Comment: Yes, I did it like you wrote. But there is one more thing. To have always actual information in database, I run CRON script everyday which checks every user in database by API's isAppUser.

Comment: I update friends on user_login, witch is lazy (positive aspect), but increases first response time.